# CRAN packages not unpacking on Ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, cran

Think I had done this type of command successfully before

```
sudo su ­ ­c "R ­e \"install.packages('countrycode', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')\""
```

the screen reports

```
Installing package into '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library'
```

which is where other packages reside

I then get

```
downloaded 28kb
```

and it just says that the source packages are in a tmp folder before returning  to the prompt

Answer (score 0):

This should work,

```
sudo R ­-e "install.packages('countrycode', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
```

You will be asked to type in your password and then it starts downloading and installation ...

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Same result. Just get same messages and end back at prompt with no request for password. BTW I am not having any problems moving files from my local computer onto the site

Comment: Actually I think the code I had used before was slightly different sudo su ­- -­c "R ­e \"install.packages('ggplot2', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')\"" but that still gives same outcome

Comment: @pssguy it is more like an issue of **permission**. I got only downloading with `sudo su - -c "R -e \"<Your-R-Command>\""`; but with `sudo R -e "<Your-R-Command>"` it works perfectly. Have you tried the steps below 1) `su` 2) `<your-password>` 3) `R -e "<Your-R-Command>"` .

Comment: I'm a complete novice here but the guy whose instructions I set up Ubunto on AWS says that the keypair I set up should give me access, which it still does for lading files from a local machine

Comment: One suggestion is that the problem has only arisen since I set up git to install non CRAN packages. This procedure still works flawlessly. Could this be the case. If so, how would I uninstall. The installation command was sudo apt-get install git. Do I just substitute remove for install and then reinstall when I want to put up another non-CRAN package or is it more complicated cheers